# PowerQuery Expression.Error: A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation

Tags: powerquery, cyclic-reference

Can't find the error in formula - the value is calculated throughout the column (when keeping errors - no rows shown), but I can't apply the changes though.((

```
if [Index] > 0 then 
if articles_pivot{[Index]-1}[IN] <> null (when omitted the error remains) and [IN]=null then
articles_pivot{[Index]-1}[IN]
else null
else null
```

Thank you for advice!

Answer (score 0):

If I an reading it right, all you really need to do is right click **IN** column and do fill ... down...

Otherwise, see if this works

```
= try if articles_pivot{[Index]-1}[IN] <> null and articles_pivot{[Index]}[IN] = null then articles_pivot{[Index]-1}[IN] else null otherwise null
```

Comment: Thank you, but the error is the same - I couldn't upload the changes. May be I should have mentioned, that it's PowerBi queries...

Comment: At the moment I'm trying to solve this problem directly in Power BI by using last non blank..

Answer (score 0):

decided to make it another way - in the origin table I've added Index column starting 0 and in the pivot table (made by pivoting the origin one) I've added index column starting 1, then merged them..)